# Occurrences of same alternative characters in a CString

Tags: c++, arrays, c-strings

I'm new to C++ programming and this is the task that i've to do, but i can't get the desired output even after trying and trying. Can anyone please look into code and let me know what  should do, i know my code is incomplete but i don't know how to proceed from here.

Task:  Write a program, using functions only, with the following features.

1. Program reads paragraph(s) from console and stores in a string.
2. Program then counts the occurrences of double letter appearing in any word of the paragraph(s) and outputs the characters along with its number of occurrences.
3. If a double letter is appearing more than one time the program should show this only one time along with its total frequency in paragraph.
4. Output letters must be in sequence.
   Sample input (file):
   Double bubble deep in the sea of tooth with teeth and meet with riddle.
   Sample output:
   bb  1
   dd  1
   ee  3
   oo  1

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int counter = 0;
char alphabets[26] = { 0 };
void alternatives();

int main() {
    alternatives();
    _getch();

    return 0;
}

void alternatives() {
    char str[] = "Double bubble deep in the sea of tooth with teeth and meet with riddle.";
    int count = 0;

    for (int j = 0; j < strlen(str); j++)
        str[j] = tolower(str[j]);

    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++) {
        if (str[i] == str[i + 1]) {
            counter++;
            cout << str[i] << str[i + 1] << "\t" << counter << endl;
        }

        counter = 0;
    }
}
```

Output:

bb      1
ee      1
oo      1
ee      1
ee      1
dd      1

Comment: Caution: CString, with that particular capitalization means [something different but similar enough to cause confusion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/using-cstring?view=msvc-170).

Comment: When `i == strlen(str) - 1`, `str[i + 1]` will be `str[strlen(str)]` which is an out of bounds access. You can loop from `i = 1` and compare `str[i-1] == str[i]`.

Comment: Make use of `alphabets`. Instead of doing `counter++`, do `alphabets[str[i] - 'a']++`. And don't do the `cout` within your second `for` loop. Use a third loop to print `alphabets`.

Comment: You're going to need some additional data structures here. Maybe something like an `std::unordered_map` from characters to how many times that character, doubled, appears in your text. Do you expect a single `counter` variable to be able to store separate values for separate letters? You also need to _not_ print anything until you've finished scanning the entire paragraph, because you're not supposed to print the same digraph multiple times and you don't know what the correct count for a given digraph is until you've reached the end of the text.

Comment: actually i'm not familiar with unordered_map , all i know till this point are cstrings and concept of 1d 2d arrays and ofc functions and some extreme basics

Comment: @rturrado It is not undefined behaviour/out of bounds access. C strings are null terminated so accessing `str[strlen(str)]` refers to the terminating 0 char. The character comparison `str[i] == str[i + 1]` never yields true in the scenario you describe, but there is no undefined behaviour caused by the read access.

Comment: @fabian Many thanks for the comment. I just saw the pattern and coded defensively :)

Answer (score 1):

You have 26 letters (I assume) so you need 26 counts. A simple array would do

```
int counters[26] = { 0 }; // initialise all counts to zero
```

Now when you find a repeated letter you need to increment the appropriate count, something like

```
for (int i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++)
{
    char letter = str[i];
    if (letter >= 'a' && letter <= 'z' && // is it a letter and
        letter == str[i + 1])             // is it repeated?
    {
        counters[letter - 'a']++;         // increment count
    }
}
```

Note the use of `letter - 'a'` to get the offset into the array of counts

Finally you need to output the results

```
for (char letter = 'a'; letter <= 'z'; ++letter)
{
     int count = counters[letter - 'a'];
     if (count > 0)
         cout << letter << letter << ' ' << count << ' ';
}
cout << '\n';
```

Not perfect, but hopefully something to get you started. This is untested code.

Comment: yes yes I got the idea ... much obliged John

Answer (score 0):

You can use an int array of length 26 to keep track of repeated instances of letters. You can then iterate over the C string and check for repeats. If you find one, make sure to jump your iterator forward.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

int main() {
    int repeats[26] = {0};

    char str[] = "Double bubble deep in the sea of tooth with teeth and meet with riddle.";
    for (char *ch = str; *ch; ch++)
        *ch = tolower(*ch);

    for (char *ch = str; *ch; ch++) {
        if (std::isalpha(*ch) && *ch == ch[1]) {
            repeats[*ch - 'a']++;
            ch++;
        }
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
        std::cout << static_cast<char>('a' + i) << ": " << repeats[i] << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
a: 0
b: 1
c: 0
d: 1
e: 3
f: 0
g: 0
h: 0
i: 0
j: 0
k: 0
l: 0
m: 0
n: 0
o: 1
p: 0
q: 0
r: 0
s: 0
t: 0
u: 0
v: 0
w: 0
x: 0
y: 0
z: 0
```